# ASP.NET MVC Routing and QueryStrings

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

Can someone please tell me why, with a url like this...

```
http://localhost:22220/groups/go/1234/2525?name=Bob
```

This route mapping doesn't match...

```
routes.MapRoute(null, // Route name
                "groups/go/{groupId}/{userId}/{name}",
                new { controller = "Groups", action = "Go" });
```

But this route mapping appears to match? (Using Phil Haack's Route Tester, this is the 'Generated URL')...

```
context.MapRoute("Teams_Default",
                 "Teams/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                 new { id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

Comment: Shouldn't the URL be `http://localhost:22220/groups/go/1234/2525/Bob` to match your route?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link needs to be :
http://localhost:22220/groups/go/1234/2525/Bob

Or you could change the route to 
"groups/go/{groupId}/{userId}"

Answer (score 0):

Since the last 'name' parameter is not formed correctly on that URL, the first route doesn't get matched. If you change the route to this:

```
routes.MapRoute(null, // Route name
                "groups/go/{groupId}/{userId}/{name}",
                new { controller = "Groups", action = "Go", name = "Bob" });
```

it will work because of the default value for 'name'.

Obviously, this is no good for you since you want the name to be read.

I think the bigger question is: How is that URL being generated?